# SQL Server : how to do an inner join by various columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, both `Table1` and `Table2`, share 4 columns named `C1, C2, C3 and C4`; those columns store a numerical sequence from 1 to 56; also, there can be not duplicated numbers in one row, and the numbers always go from lowest to highest.

Example:

Table1

```
C1 C2 C3 C4
 1  6 10 44
 5  7 23 50
45 46 52 56
```

Now I have to check for sequences that appear in the two tables, but instead of a join on the four columns

```
select * 
from table1 a 
inner join table 2 on a.c1 = b.c1 and a.c2 = b.c2 and a.c3 = b.c3 and a.c4 = b.c4
```

is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a different way, use [INTERSECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/ms188055.aspx).

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4
FROM table1
INTERSECT
SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4
FROM table2
```

Note: This will not tell you how many times a match is found, it will show the unique matches between the tables